# how to run two sites from single ip using relative paths with out domain name in nginx

Tags: nginx

hi I was wondering if we could run two sites with same ip 
 eg: using an ip directly without any domain name like accessing 192.168.4.250 should give me access to a site "site1" and using a relative path like 192.168.4.250/example to give acess to "site 2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason why not, you would just end up in the 'default' server for that ip address. The two "sites" would need to live within the same 'server' (though you could use includes or send to another local port of you want to have independent configurations):

```
server {
  listen 192.168.4.250;
  server_name _;


  location /example {
     root /site_2;
     # OR
     # proxy_pass http://localhost:SOMEPORT2
  }

  location / {
     root /site_1;
     # OR
     # proxy_pass http://localhost:SOMEPORT;
  }
```

}